# Time-out has expired. The time-out period has expired before a connection was obtained from the group

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, iis, timeout

I am getting weird issue when i change deployment environment to my old ASP.net application . I migrated my ASP.net application from IIS 7 (windows server 2008 ) to IIS 8 (windows server 2012) ,application is running very well on old server but on new server i sometime get weird timeout issue . i have searched for my problem but i think i am the first one who is getting this issue :( . I even cant figure out, is this issue related to IIS timeout /session timeout or SQL timeout .

```
Time-out has expired. The time-out period has expired before a connection was obtained from the group. A possible cause is that all connections in the group have been in use and the maximum group was reached.
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an application that isn't properly closing or disposing of the SqlConnection objects. By default, SqlConnection has a max pool size of 100.

The fix here would be to work with the application to find out why connections aren't being cleaned up, as they are still "active" in the particular connection pool, which is why you are unable to grab another one, because there are no inactive connections in the pool to use.

The application should be making a call to SqlConnection.Close() or SqlConnection.Dispose() in order to release the connection and mark it as "inactive".